# change abbreviationstyle locally

Tags: acronyms, glossaries-extra

Is there a possibility to change the `abbreviationstyle` locally from `long-short` to `short-long`?

E.g. in the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ac:cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\newacronym{ac:cae}{CAE}{Computer Aided Engineering}
\newacronym{ac:cam}{CAM}{Computer Aided Manufacturing}

\begin{document}

\gls{ac:cad}

\gls{ac:cae}

\gls{ac:cam}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Would it be possible to change the `abbreviationstyle` for the acronym "CAE" (or any other if wanted) and only for this one without affecting the others?

Edit:

with the additional command `\CAE` (see MWE below) it does work, but is really clunky, as I have to manually call the respective acronym several times (glsxtrshort, glsxtrlong, ifglsused and glsunset).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{ac:cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\newacronym{ac:cae}{CAE}{Computer Aided Engineering}
\newacronym{ac:cam}{CAM}{Computer Aided Manufacturing}

\newcommand{\CAE}{%
    \glsxtrshort{ac:cae}\ifglsused{ac:cae}{}{~(\glsxtrlong{ac:cae}\glsunset{ac:cae}}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \gls{ac:cad}
    
    \CAE
    
    \CAE
    
    \gls{ac:cam}
    
    \printglossaries
    
\end{document}
```

Is there any possibility to pass the acronym name (in this case `ac:cae`) once to all of the aforementioned commands to minimize errors on my side if I should do this not only for one acronym but for multiple?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in case you just want to avoid the long form, that can easily be done by setting the appropriate flag for that entry.

Comment: Do you mean '\glsxtrshort'?

Comment: No, I mean `\glsunset`.

Comment: @schtandard please see the edit in my post, is this how you thought to do it? If not, could you please elaborate how you intended to do it or maybe streamline my approach?